# Why is it bad to make elements global variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, events, global

I've heard that it's not a good idea to make elements global in JavaScript. I don't understand why. Is it something IE can't handle?

For example:

```
    div = getElementById('topbar');
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Event handlers? Global variables? Event handlers attached via on/event/= attributes in the markup?

Comment: Do you mean global variables?  Can you rephrase your question or provide some sample code?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'elements' like div = document.getElementById('topbar'), not 'events'. I'll fix my question.

Comment: I think you're talking about variables in general rather than 'elements'. In JavaScript, variables are exactly the same no matter what they contain/point to (e.g. DOM elements, strings, arrays).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that's an implementation issue, but more a good vs bad practice issue. Usually global * is bad practice and should be avoided (global variables and so on) since you never really know how the scope of the project will evolve and how your file will be included.

I'm not a big JS freak so I won't be able to give you the specifics on exactly why JS events are bad but [Christian Heilmann talks about JS best practices here](http://www.slideshare.net/cheilmann/javascript-best-practices-1041724), you could take a look. Also try googling "JS best practices"

Edit: Wikipedia about global variables, that could also apply to your problem :

> [global variables] are usually
>   considered bad practice precisely
>   because of their nonlocality: a global
>   variable can potentially be modified
>   from anywhere, (unless they reside in
>   protected memory) and any part of the
>   program may depend on it. A global
>   variable therefore has an unlimited
>   potential for creating mutual
>   dependencies, and adding mutual
>   dependencies increases complexity. See
>   Action at a distance. However, in a
>   few cases, global variables can be
>   suitable for use. For example, they
>   can be used to avoid having to pass
>   frequently-used variables continuously
>   throughout several functions.

via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable

Answer (score 4):

> Is it something IE can't handle?

**No** it is not an IE thing. You can never assume that your code will  be the only script used in the document. So it is important that you make sure your code does not have global function or variable names that other scripts can override.

Refer to [Play Well With Others](http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache:zzyCvm7mUdcJ:icant.co.uk/articles/seven-rules-of-unobtrusive-javascript/+why+not+make+events+global+in+js&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "events" you mean the event-handling JavaScript (functions).

In general, it's bad to use more than one global variable in JS.  (It's impossible not to use at least one if you're storing any data for future use.)  That's because it runs into the same problem as all [namespacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_(computer_science)) tries to solve - what if you wrote a method doSomething() and someone else wrote a method called doSomething()?

The best way to get around this is to make a global variable that is an object to hold all of your data and functions.  For example:

```
var MyStuff = {};
MyStuff.counter = 0;
MyStuff.eventHandler = function() { ... };
MyStuff.doSomething = function() { ... };

// Later, when you want to call doSomething()...
MyStuff.doSomething();
```

This way, you're minimally polluting the global namespace; you only need worry that someone else uses your global variable.

Of course, none of this is a problem if your code will never play with anyone else's...  but this sort of thinking will bite you in the ass later if you ever do end up using someone else's code.  As long as everyone plays nice in terms of JS global names, all code can get along.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, what I meant was not 'event', it was 'element'. Something like div = document.getElementById('topbar').

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem using global variables in your code as long as you are wrapping them inside a uniqe namespase/object (to avoid collision with scripts that are not yours)

the main adventage of using global variable in javascript derives from the fact that javascript is not a strong type language. there for, if you pass somes complex objects as arguments to a function, you will probebly lose all the intellisence for those objects (inside the function scope.) 
while using global objects insteads, will preserve that intellisence.

I personally find that very usfull and it certainly have place in my code.

(of course, one should alwayse make the right balance between locales and globals variables)